# PHP code function not working properly

Tags: php, geojson

I have a PHP file where I use the following PHP code to access my DB to retrieve some data to create a geojson. It does return a geojson but all html etc is exluded when i call this function.

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");
$geo = connectToDB::getGeoJSON();
?>
```

This is the function im calling from another a db.php file.

```
    public static function getGeoJSON() {

    $db_connection = new mysqli(mysqlServer, mysqlUser, mysqlPass, mysqlDB);
    $statement = $db_connection->prepare("Select poiId, lat,lng,description from poi");
    $statement->bind_result( $id, $lat, $lng, $description);
    $statement->execute();

    $feature = array();

    $geojson = array(
        'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
        'features'  => $feature
    );

    while ($statement->fetch()) {
        $feature = array(
            'type' => 'Feature',
            'geometry' => array(
                'type' => 'Point',
                'coordinates' => array($lng, $lat)
            ),
            'properties' => array(
                'description' => $description
                //Other fields here, end without a comma
            )
        );
        array_push($geojson, $feature);
    }

    $statement->close();
    $db_connection->close();
    //Return routing result
    header("Content-Type:application/json",true);

    return $geojson;

}
```

Can anyone see whats wrong with the code? It does return the correct output but then the rest of the page wont show. Other functions I call is working normally so its the geojson function something is wrong with.

Comment: `but all html etc is exluded`... um, what HTML? Also, you set Content-Type to json, so what output are you expecting?

Comment: What is your error Message?

Comment: it could be any html code. All that is seen is the bare-code since the php apparently fails, but it does print the output

Comment: Lets start off with this, `mysqlServer`, `mysqlUser` etc. is not available in the scope of your static method.

Comment: Just a guess : it might just be because of your `header("Content-Type:application/json",true);` line, the browser interprets this page as a JSON, therefore it doesn't show the HTML.

Comment: yes it was the header. Thanks.